# Postgresql TODATETIMEOFFSET function

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Is there a way to create a postgresql function that mimcs Sql server TODATETIMEOFFSET?
Basically, I need to retrieve the current timestamp + offset given an offset.
E.g: consider the following query:
`select current_timestamp,  TODATETIMEOFFSET(current_timestamp,'-03:00')`
It should return "2023-07-12 13:54:11.930 -03:00"

For testing purpose, I've tried using the following code, but it does not work as expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TODATETIMEOFFSET(
  timestamp_without_timezone TIMESTAMPTZ,
  time_zone_offset VARCHAR
) RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AS $$
DECLARE
  v_tz_name varchar;
  curr_tz varchar;
  v_return varchar;
BEGIN
    select name into v_tz_name from pg_timezone_names where utc_offset = time_zone_offset::interval limit 1;
    
    --get the current tz 
    select current_setting('TIMEZONE') into curr_tz;
    
    --EXECUTE 'SET TIME ZONE ''' || v_tz_name || ''';' ;
    EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL TIME ZONE ''' || v_tz_name || ''';' ;
    
    select current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone v_tz_name into v_return;
    
    --rollback the session tz
    EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL TIME ZONE ''' || curr_tz || ''';' ;
    
    --EXECUTE 'SET TIME ZONE ''' || curr_tz || ''';' ;
    
    RETURN v_return;
  --RETURN timestamp_without_timezone + time_zone_offset::interval;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `select  to_char(current_timestamp - '3 hrs'::interval, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS OF') ; 2023-07-12 05:33:39.445-07`

Comment: Also you can use [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) to deal with this by using `ISO` output format e.g. `show datestyle ISO, MDY` then `select  current_timestamp - '3 hrs'::interval;  2023-07-12 05:49:17.756547-07`.